# Multiple Table Android SQLite with Loader Callbacks

Tags: android, android-sqlite, loader

I'm trying to create a patient registration app in android but I'm currently stuck on how to achieved a multiple table to relate with and add to loader callback method.

The First table is for patient fullname.
And the Second table is for patient information foreign key to the id of the patient_fullname table.

Can someone here explain or help me on how to achieved this output?

Appreciate for any help.

PatienDBOpenHelper.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class PatientDBOpenHelper extends  SQLiteOpenHelper{
    //Constants for db name and version
    private static final String LOGTAG = "DENTALAPP";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dental.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Constants for identifying table and columns
    public static final String TABLE_PATIENT = "patient";
    public static final String PATIENT_ID = "_id";
    public static final String PATIENT_NAME = "nameInfo";
    public static final String PATIENT_GENDER = "genderInfo";
    public static final String PATIENT_CREATED = "patientCreated";

    /*I will put my desired table structure here
    _id
    patientId
    address
    occupation
    etc....
    */

    public static final String[] ALL_COLUMNS = {PATIENT_ID, PATIENT_NAME, PATIENT_GENDER,PATIENT_CREATED};

    //SQL to create table
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE_PATIENT =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PATIENT + " (" +
                    PATIENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    PATIENT_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                    PATIENT_GENDER + " TEXT, " +
                    PATIENT_CREATED + " TEXT default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" +
                    ")";

    /*
    Will also add query statement here for another table.
     */

    public PatientDBOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        /*
        Add the creation of other table.
         */

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_PATIENT);
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"Table Created!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        /*
        Add the query of my additional drop table.
         */
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_PATIENT);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
}
```

PatientDataSource.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.bloxofcode.multipletabs.model.Patient;

public class PatientDataSource {
    private static final String LOGTAG = "DENTALAPP";
    SQLiteOpenHelper dbhelper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;

    public PatientDataSource(Context context){
        dbhelper = new PatientDBOpenHelper(context);
    }

    public void open(){
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"Database open");
        database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close(){
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"Database close");
        dbhelper.close();
    }

    public Patient create(Patient patient){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(PatientDBOpenHelper.PATIENT_NAME,patient.getPatientFullName());
        values.put(PatientDBOpenHelper.PATIENT_GENDER,patient.getPatientGender());
        long id = database.insert(PatientDBOpenHelper.TABLE_PATIENT,null,values);
        patient.setId(id);
        return patient;
    }
}
```

Tab1.java

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
    private ImageButton imgButton;
    private CustomDialog customDialog;
    private TextView tvNoRecord;
    private ImageView imgNoRecord;
    private CursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
    PatientDataSource patientDataSource;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        patientDataSource = new PatientDataSource(getActivity());
        patientDataSource.open();
        final View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);
        imgButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imgNoRecord = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgNoRecord);
        tvNoRecord = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNoRecord);
        //Creating ImageButton
        imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                customDialog = new CustomDialog(getActivity());
                customDialog.setDialogResult(new OnMyDialogResult() {
                    @Override
                    public void finish(String resultName, String resultGender) {
                        if (!resultName.isEmpty()){
                            Log.d("TestingUnit","asdadasdsa");
                            Patient patient = new Patient();
                            patient.setPatientFullName(resultName);
                            patient.setPatientGender(resultGender);
                            patientDataSource.create(patient);
                            restartLoader();
                        }
                        listPatient(v);
                    }
                });
                customDialog.show();
            }
        });

        listPatient(v);
        return v;
    }

    private void listPatient(View v){
        cursorAdapter = new PatientCursorAdapter(getActivity(),null,0 );
        ListView list = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String info = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName)).getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), UserInfoActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("PersonName", info);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);
    }

    private void restartLoader(){
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0,null,this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), PatientProvider.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        if(data.getCount() > 0){
            imgNoRecord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tvNoRecord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            imgNoRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNoRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        patientDataSource.open();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        patientDataSource.close();
    }
}
```

This is where i will get the 1st table(patient full name):

[image]

This is where the 2nd table will show its data(patient info):

[image]